# Let $C_1$ be the curve parametrized by $r_1(t) =\langle\sqrt{t},t\rangle,t\geq0$ and let $C_2$ be the curve parameterized by ,

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

$r_2(u)=<u,\frac{10}{u}+c>$, $u>0$, where c is a constant.

(a) Suppose $c=-1$. Find a point at which the two curves intersect.$$$$
(b) Find a value of $c \neq -1$ for which the curves intersect orthogonally.
$$$$

$$$$
My Solution (a):
$$r_1(t) = <\sqrt{t},t>,r_2(u)=<u,\frac{10}{u}+c>, c = -1$$
$$\sqrt{t} = u,\frac{10}{u}-1=t$$
$$ u = 2 , t = 4$$
$$x = \sqrt{4}=2$$

$$y = 4$$
Point is $$(2,4)$$

My Solution (b):
$$r_1(t) = <\sqrt{t},t>,r_2(u)=<u,\frac{10}{u}+c>$$
$$\sqrt{t}=u, t = \frac{10}{u}+c, r(t)\cdot r(u)=0$$
$$r(t)\cdot r(u)=(\sqrt{t})(u) + (t)(\frac{10}{u}+c) = 0 $$
$$\sqrt{t}=u, t = \frac{10}{u}+c, (\sqrt{t})(u) + (t)(\frac{10}{u}+c) = 0$$
$$t=4,u=2,c=-9$$
Final Answer:
$$c=-9$$

Any feedback on my solutions if they are correct would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: If $t=4$ and $u=2$, $\sqrt{t}u+t(\frac{10}{u}+c)=2\sqrt{4}+4(\frac{10}{2}+c)=4+4(5+c)=24+4c$.Then $c=-6$

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)